# Nuget Package Manager for Mac

Tags: macos, xamarin, nuget

I was trying to follow this video on youtube "How to create nuget packages" - I went to nuget.org and found all the downloads are .exe - How do I do this for mac?? Any idea??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nuget itself is written in C#, you run nuget using Mono on Mono platforms. e.g:

```
$ mono nuget.exe
```

When running nuget, you may encounter errors. You may need to copy `Microsoft.Build.dll` from a .NET installation to the same path as nuget. For example, copy both `nuget.exe` and `Microsoft.Build.dll` to `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: Thank you - I realized the commands do work

Answer (score 4):

The `Mono` framework include a shell script that wraps `nuget.exe` and it is already included in your path:

```
>which nuget
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands/nuget

>cat `which nuget`
#!/bin/sh
exec /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.4.1/bin/mono $MONO_OPTIONS /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.4.1/lib/mono/nuget/nuget.exe "$@"
```

So at a shell prompt, you can just type `nuget`:

```
>nuget
NuGet Version: 4.3.0.4406
usage: NuGet <command> [args] [options]
Type 'NuGet help <command>' for help on a specific command.
~~~
```

Comment: Keep in mind this is only true if you've installed the Mono framework package. If you build from source neither nuget nor the wrapper exist.

Comment: @CinderBiscuits The question is flagged `Xamarin` ;-)